# SSL Redirection in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl-certificate

how can we redirect "http://www.example.com" to "https://www.example.com" when any user types "http://www.example.com" in cakePHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a .htacces file to do it before loading any php. Then the servers doesn't need to load the PHP scripts

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

While the currently accepted answer focuses on the use of apache's `rewrite` module, there are a number of cases where this answer doesn't apply, for an obvious example when apache isn't used at all or when rewrite module isn't and can't be enabled.

So a more generic answer would involve you adding this to your `AppController`

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    if (!env('HTTPS')) {
        return $this->redirect('https://' . $this->request->host() . $this->request->here(), 301);
    }
}
```

Which would make a permanent redirect to the same url under https if https isn't used.

You don't specify cake's version so the above is cakephp 3 code, just remove `Event $event` from the function arguments to make it cake 2.